# HP ProCurve 4208vl - Show PSU information?

Tags: networking, hardware, hp, hp-procurve, power-supply-unit

I'm working with a few older [HP ProCurve 4200-series chassis switches](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/networking-switches/product-detail.html?oid=1827689) (4204vl and 4208vl).

Some of these units have single power supplies, while others have dual power supplies. I'm trying to inventory the switch configurations, but the devices are remote and I don't have physical access.

Is there any way to query ProCurve 4200vl chassis power supply status or count from the command line?

[image]

---

The higher-end [HP ProCurve 5400zl switches](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/networking-switches/product-detail.html?oid=1827663) are able to show this info via the `sh power-over-ethernet` command.

```
valley-core# show power-over-ethernet

 Status and Counters - System Power Status

  System Power Status    : No redundancy
  PoE Power Status       : No redundancy

 Chassis power-over-ethernet:

  Total Available Power  : 1200 W
  Total Failover Power   :  900 W
  Total Redundancy Power :    0 W
  Total Used Power       :  340 W +/- 6W
  Total Remaining Power  :  860 W

 Internal Power

        Main Power
  PS    (Watts)       Status
  ----- ------------- ---------------------
  1     300           POE+ Connected
  2     300           POE+ Connected
  3     300           POE+ Connected
  4     300           POE+ Connected
```